# Separate Text file to columns by ;

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

Please I have a text file separated by spaces. I would like to output it to columns separated by ;

example
Input

```
31561 49215 10   1196825801480000
31561 49219 12   1196825801480000
31561 48665 14   1196825806980000
```

I use this code

```
tr " " ";" < file
```

My output

```
31561;49215;10;;;1196825801480000
31561;49219;12;;;1196825801480000
31561;48665;14;;;1196825806980000
```

Output desired.

```
31561;49215;10;1196825801480000
31561;49219;12;1196825801480000
31561;48665;14;1196825806980000
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

`$1=$1` is a trick to rebuild `$0` with the new separator `OFS=';'`.

Comment: @EdMorton Can't argue with you about `awk` ;) Thanks, **again**! Broken code and it saved only 3 characters.

Answer (score 4):

`sed -r 's/ +/;/g' < file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
    tr -s " " ";" < file
```

and read the manual: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tr/

> -s
>   Squeeze multiple occurrences of the characters listed in the last operand (either string1 or string2) in the input into a single instance of the character. This occurs after all deletion and translation is completed.